# Аналог static class (C#) на Java

Tags: java, android

Нагуглил несколько статей: в одной говорится, что синглтон идеален для хранения глобальных переменных. В другой - что он (синглтон) таки может быть уничтожен, и  значения всех глобальных переменных исчезнут.

Вопрос у меня такой: в C# я объявлял `static class`, и мог пользоваться его содержимым везде по коду. В этом классе главными были именно переменные (свойства), с методами ситуация была не так критична. Что в Java наиболее близко к `static class` в C#?

Скорее всего, все же, ближе по смыслу синглтон - но тогда другой вопрос - в каких ситуациях он может быть удален системой, если я буду хранить ссылку на него в `MainActivity`?

Comment: Объявляйте класс и используйте в нем статические методы и атрибуты. Все будет сохранено. Обращение по ИмениКласса.ИмяМетодаИлиАтрибута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton и статический класс, это две принципиально разные вещи.

[Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) - паттерн проектирования, который гарантирует, что можно создать лишь один единственный экземпляр данного класса.

Статический класс - класс экземпляры, которого не возможно создать. В Java такое предусмотрено только для вложенных классов. Правда есть способ эмулировать статический класс для классов верхнего уровня.

Если Вам от такого класса нужны только некие константы, лучше объявить их в интерфейсе. Если же Вам нужен ещё и функционал, используйте Singleton, но ссылку на него храните в главном классе программы и инициализацию делайте там же.

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения статических констант удобно сделать интерфейс - в интерфейсе все поля public static final.
Активити в андроид уничтожается даже при повороте экрана, поэтому и ссылка на синглтон может потеряться и сборщик мусора его убьет.